# Where is PHPUnit?

Tags: php, phpunit, pear

**Resolved!**

I uninstalled phpunit from pear and then reinstalled it again.  I believe I was using the wrong/old/not enough sources before installing.  Works like a charm!

---

So I'm trying to set up PEAR & PHPUnit.  I was following http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/page/install-pear-phpunit-xdebug-on-macosx-snow-leopard but after I installed pear I had a different directory structure in /usr/local.  Regardless, I was able run the phpunit install.  But now I'm lost and asking for help before I make a bigger mess :)

pear config-show says:

```
PEAR directory                 php_dir          /usr/local/share/pear
```

And my php.ini file (and confirmed in phpinfo() says:

```
include_path=".:/usr/local/share/pear"
```

So that's good, right?  But now what?  I get

> Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Framework.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/share/pear')

If I try to include it in the php.  And I have no idea where the binary might be to run it from the command line.

Inside `/usr/local/share/pear/PHPUnit` there are two directories `"Extensions"` and `"Framework"`

Comment: You might be following instructions for an older version of PHPUnit. It should install the binary in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`. Look for `phpunit` in those directories. What version of PHPUnit did PEAR say it installed? Also, the folder inside `PHPUnit` should be `Framework` (not plural). Was the `s` just a typo? Is there a file called `Framework.php` in the `PHPUnit` folder?

Comment: Oops, yes that was a typo on Framework.  But there is no Framework.php inside.  Just MockObject.  And inside MockObject a whole bunch of stuff.   I'm not sure which version of PHPUnit it installed.

Comment: @speg: Do you see the file `Framework.php` inside the PHPUnit directory?

Comment: No, just a Framework directory.  (which inside of that is just a MockObject directory).  

There is also no binary to be found in /usr/local/bin or /usr/bin

I'm starting to think the install is old or didn't finish properly?

Comment: Please post your resolution as an answer using the form below instead.

Answer (score 6):

It sometimes happen that the install fails on PHPUnit specifically, but succeeds on the dependencies, so it only **looks** like the install was succesfull.

Try this when installing

```
pear install --force --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

The `--force` option will force the install of PHPUnit, even if all the dependencies can't be met. In my case there was a missing dependency for the dom PHP extension which blocked the installation even though the `PHP_Invoker` package could be used instead.

The `--alldeps` option makes sure that all of the dependencies got installed.

Answer (score 3):

Check for a bin directory in the pear install, something along the lines of `/usr/local/share/pear/bin/` - your install is different than mine..

You could also try searching for the binary -

```
find /usr/local/share/pear -name 'phpunit'
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me get going in the right direction to find the correct path on my file system - Mac OS X Mavericks.  For me, the path was: /usr/lib/php/pear/PHPUnit/Extensions/